# Laravel @ https is not working on server where {!! forms !!} are loaded

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm continue working with project, which was ignored by developer :(

So, website is already on Server and last thing is turn ON - HTTPS.

I checked, that on localhost everything is working, fine, BUT:

on server, also everything is fine, except {!! forms !!} they are loaded through HTTP, not HTTS

Just, short example on localhost:

```
<form method="GET" action="https://localhost/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form form-inline executor_search" role="form">
```

Same example (page) on server:

```
<form method="GET" action="http://mywebsite/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form form-inline executor_search" role="form">
```

In **config/app.php** url is

> httpS

In resources/view/layout.blade.php

> {secure_asset} to load css and js files.

So, website is loaded over HTTPS everywhere, except pages where forms are displayed.

Comment: Have you tried `clear:cache`  ?

Comment: Only one way I see is, to change laravel form generator , to plain HTML                 <form method="GET" action="https://mywebsite/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form form-inline executor_search" role="form">

Comment: @MahdiYounesi I will try ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in the `boot` method of your `AppServiceProvider` file

```
\URL::forceSchema('https');
```

Comment: @p-pjotrs try without check production

Comment: URL::forceSchema('https');
site loaded over HTTPS, but white screen, and in error logs, something wrong... warning about URL class

Comment: nope ;(Class 'lluminate\\Support\\Facades\\URL' not found

Comment: @p-pjotrs if i help you, please, chek my answer

Answer (score 0):

add this to the top of your routes file and see if it helps

```
if (env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
    URL::forceSchema('https');
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to open file

```
app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
```

After

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
```

to Add

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
```

In section

```
public function boot()
{
    ...
}
```

Add next Line
If you use old version up to 5.4

```
URL::forceSchema('https');
```

If you use version newer than 5.4

```
URL::forceScheme('https');
```

difference in one letter "a" "e" forceSchemA forceSchemE.

Cheers ;-)